# what are the difference between metric space and metric linear space?

Tags: functional-analysis

I know the meaning of metric space and vector space. but i want to differentiate metric space from metric linear space. so basically what are metric space and linear space?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the graph of $y=x^2$ where $x\in[0,1]$. This is a metric space that is not linear.

A metric and linearity are simply different structures that can be imposed on sets (simultaneously if necessary).

Comment: Or you can take any line segment in the plane too.

Answer (score 0):

"Linear space" is just a synonym for "vector space".  A metric linear space is something that is both a metric space and a vector space, such that the vector space operations (addition and scalar multiplication) are both jointly continuous.

Comment: But aren't all vector spaces metric spaces?

Comment: I guess I'm questioning whether or not the term "linear metric space" refers to a space that is both a vector space and a metric space, when in fact *all* vector spaces are indeed metric spaces. Using the terminology "linear metric space" in your context suggests a question: can we find a space that is a vector space but not a metric space?

Comment: but my question was what are the differences between metric space and metric linear space?

Comment: All vector spaces **can be made into** metric spaces by adding additional structure, namely a metric.  The same can be said of all sets.

Comment: i understood that all vector space can be made metric space by imposing metric properties. but can we make metric space a vector space? i mean all vector spaces are metric space. are all metric spaces vector space?

Comment: can anyone tell me the difference between metric space and metric linear space in points?

Comment: The group of homeomorphisms of a metric linear space onto itself acts transitively.  For example, if some points of a metric space are isolated and others are not, you can't make this into a metric linear space.